# The data I return with ajax sometimes goes into an if block and sometimes an else block

Tags: javascript, ajax, abp

after the return from the Abp service, data goes into if block and sometimes else block. However after the returned data, it must be included in the if block. Why do this happen? Btw data is coming true, checks were done. I mean the res is bigger than totalprice.

```
abc.services.score.getScore().then(function (res) {

                $('#totalScore').text(res + ' TL');
                if (res> totalPrice) {
                    $('#scoreModal').show();
                }
                else {
                    swal("test");
                }
                
            });
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(res)`?

Comment: res: 7373.03 totalPrice: 120

Comment: But is it `7373.03` or `"7373.03"` ?

Comment: I checked the incoming type is number.

Comment: Then, given all the information provided here, there is absolutely no reason why `if (res> totalPrice)` would not always evaluate to `true`. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Btw we have seen such an error in the prod. Sometimes it's working sometimes doesn't working in the prod with same data.

Comment: It's impossible. `if (res>totalPrice)` will ALWAYS resolve the same way, given `res` and `totalPrice` have a defined and known value. Code execution is not random. Your data is changing, log it.